# How can live modifying a Lottie object not cause image pop-ins on Safari?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, safari, lottie

We are using Lottie to display a preview of how our app would look like on a user’s phone, and we enable our user to modify the colours that make it up to customise it to their liking.

To modify these colours live, we use regex to pick out the colours in the JSON file and replace them with the newly selected one. This works fine and is quite smooth on Chrome. However, for some reason, this is not fine on Safari and causes the image object (the only one in the JSON, I suspect had there been more they would have all behaved similarly) to pop in and out.

Below are GIF examples (not rep'd enough to post directly):

#### [Chrome (Working)](https://media.giphy.com/media/fSqGJoef2IG0H4wY46/giphy.gif)

#### [Safari (Pop-ins)](https://media.giphy.com/media/WSCNVmey2CrDjA1342/giphy.gif)

So we are using Lottie with React, and I thought maybe it would be possible to pre-render the change in colour before updating the DOM, but I’ve not found much in the way of changing the order of execution to get this effect. I also found that there used to be a param literally called “prerender” that can be passed as an option, but apparently, that has been [“deprecated” since 2017](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/266).

I have also tried different render methods (there are 3: HTML, SVG, Canvas), neither of which have worked. Below is the current list of options we pass to the Lottie object.

```
const option = {
    renderer: "svg",
    animationData: animationData,
    prerender: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    rendererSettings: {
        preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
    }
};
```

I have also discovered that changing anything in the state that might cause any part of the DOM the Lottie object is associated with to re-render, will also cause the image pop-in. I’m currently thinking this might just be a Lottie and Safari issue that has no fix, without scrapping Lottie and utilising a different method to preview the app in the browser that is.

Any thoughts what might be causing this, or have any solutions to fix it?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering if I found a solution, I did not. I think it is silly to use Lottie in this way anyway, but that is the direction we went here... I guess we gotta live with the flickering.